# input поле только для цифр html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть поле  `<input class="ss" type="text">`
Вешаю на него событие:

```
$(".ss").keyup(function(e){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});
```

В итоге при вводе буквы её видно на мгновение, а потом она убирается. Как сделать чтобы её не было видно? Так же ещё и «.» надо.

Answer (score 8):

Всё, что вам нужно это:

```html
<input type="number">
```

---

В случае, если вдруг это не подходит, ответ на [eng.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input). Мне больше всего понравился вариант:

`<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />`

And this script:

```
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: ОТЛИЧНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ!!!
Подскажите, как добавить в этот скрипт ограничение максимального и минимального числа в input? Мне нужен диапазон 1-255. При вводе 300, например, - сброс значения на 255. При вводе 0 - сброс на 1.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Можно просто запретить ввод ненужных символов - например, только цифры и точки:

```js
$(".ss").keypress(function(event){
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.charCode && event.charCode!=0 && event.charCode!=46 && (event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode > 57) )
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ss" type="text">
```

Comment: точку или запятую нельзя.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko ну так все желаемые символы можно добавить. отредактировал для цифр и точки

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего эту задачу решить через event 'input'. Он используется в чисто в (vamilla js). Аналога, к сожалению, в jq нет. Вот код, который решит эту задачку.

p.s. я немного доработал регулярку

```
document.querySelector('.ss').addEventListener('input', 
    function(e){
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    }
)
```

Автор ответа: Гайк Инанц, преподаватель HackerU

Answer (score 3):

Используй не событие **keyup**, а событие **input**, и тогда всё будет гуд!

```
$(".ss").on('input', function(e){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.key.length == 1 && e.key.match(/[^0-9'".]/)){
    return false;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не могу писать комментарии, так что напишу тут. 
Если используете jquery, почему не заюзать маску на поле?
[jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Там везде маски, мне же нужно просто ввод чисел с одной точкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="ss" type="text" onkeypress="banText()>
<script>
function banText() {
    let banText = parseFloat(event.key);

    if (isNaN(banText) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log(banText);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

В input установите атрибут step= 0.1